# Troubleshooting Firebase Authentication Setup

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm taking the Firebase Authentication service for a trial run. And having some initial Qs:

- Howto use the [accountChooser](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#using-firebaseui-for-authentication) ?
- Howto enable Twitter & Github access ? ie, it's not clear to me, where we get the

  1. API key
  2. API secret
  3. Callback URL for Twitter or for an example?
- From where do I get the correct `apiKey` and `authDomain`?

*fig.1*

```
var config = {
  apiKey: “<key-from-google-console>”, 
  authDomain: "<my-app>.firebaseapp.com" 
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

I got my current values from the Google API Manager Creds Dashboard. But when I press the <kbd>Sign in with Google</kbd> button, I get the error:

*fig.2* (on firebase-ui-auth.js:206)

```
Internal error: 
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. I was using an `apiKey: “<key-from-google-console>”,` from my existing, external google account. The easiest thing to do was to use the `apiKey` from my new Firebase account.

There's probably a way to use previous / existing Google apiKeys. I just haven't figured that out yet.

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable authentication for the sign in methods I was using in the Firebase Console

Answer (score -1):

I'm creating registration form and trying to connect to firebase but nothing showing up in firebase authentication and when I click on register button I get this line of output, I have enabled password/email in sign-in user as well.

An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33209295)